# how to filter multidimensional array. php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have some confusing issue here. please take a look and help if you don't mind.

let's say i have this multidimensional array, called $array.

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [3] => 2
            [2] => 5
            [4] => 4
        )
[3] => Array
    (
        [1] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [1] => 5
    )
```

that array is representing a path between two node. I try to implmenting dijkstra algorhitm here. when it's 
`$array[1][2] = 5` 
that's mean the distance between node 1 to node 2 is 5 and so on.

what Im asking is, how can I detect that array `$array[1][4] = 4` doesn't have a reverse path such `$array[4][1] = 4` like the example above.

thank you in advance.

Comment: do you want to add reverse path $array[4][1] = 4 to array?

Comment: no.. I want to detect that $array[4][1] = 4 has no the reverse array like another one.

Comment: @punk73 see solution for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this:

```
 $temp = array();

 $array = array('1' => Array
    (
    '3' => 2,
    '2' => 5,
    '4' => 4
),
'3' => Array
    (
    '1' => 2
),
'2' => Array
    (
    '1' => 5
    ));

 foreach ($array as $key => $value)
 {
    foreach ($value as $k => $v)
    {
       if($array[$key][$k] == isset($array[$k][$key]))
       {
        echo $key . 'to' . $k . 'reverse path available';
        echo "<br>";
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: no need to check isset($array[$key][$k]) by using foreach loop,

Answer (score 1):

Like this.Loop foreach inside another foreach and check based on keys.

```
   $array = array('1'=>array('3'=>2),'3'=>array('1'=>2));//assumed reversed array
//print_r($array);

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        foreach($value as $k=>$v){
            if($array[$key][$k] == $array[$k][$key]){
           echo "Reverse at:array[".$key."][".$k."]".PHP_EOL;
           continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Reverse at:array[1][3]
Reverse at:array[3][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

for that array you have to add nested for loop..

```
for($i=0;$i<count($your_array);$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<count($your_array[$i]);$j++)
    {
       if(isset($your_array[$i][$j]) && isset($your_array[$j][$i]) && $your_array[$i][$j]==$your_array[$j][$i])
       {
          echo "same distance";
       }
       else
       {
          echo "different distance or path not available";
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: no need to check isset($your_array[$i][$j]) by using foreach loop, by using foreach loop it is became more easier and efficient and take less time to run.

Comment: In my answer there no any foreach loop... vaibhav raychura... please check code 1st...

Comment: yes i know that's why i'm saying please use foreach loop so solution became more simple pAsh..